# What is the responsibility of (.*) in the Java String?

Tags: java, regex, string

What is the responsibility of `(.*)` in the third line and how it works?

```
String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");
System.out.print("Return Value :" );
System.out.println(Str.matches("(.*)Tutorials(.*)"));
```

Comment: Never use a constructor in `String` like this.

Comment: Only experts should write tutorials, there a many mistakes in that very short piece of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.matches()` is a call to parse `Str` using the regex provided.

[Regex, or Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), are a way of parsing strings into groups. In the example provided, this matches any string which contains the word "Tutorials". `(.*)` simply means "a group of zero or more of any character".

[This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) is a good regex reference (for very basic syntax and examples).

Answer (score 4):

Your expression **matches** any word prefixed and suffixed by any character of word `Tutorial`. `.*` means occurrence of any character any number of times including zero times.

The `.` represents regular expression [meta-character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) which means **any character**.

The `*` is a regular expression [quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html), which **means 0 or more occurrences** of the expression character it was associated with.

Answer (score 2):

`matches` takes [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) string as parameter and `(.*)` means capture any character zero or more times greedily

Answer (score 2):

`.*` means a group of zero or more of any character

Answer (score 2):

In `Regex`:

> ***`.`***
>
> Wildcard: Matches any single character except `\n`

for example pattern `a.e` matches `ave` in `nave` and `ate` in `water`

> ***`*`***
>
> Matches the previous element zero or more times

for example pattern `\d*\.\d` matches `.0`, `19.9`, `219.9`

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to put parentheses around the `.*`, nor is there a reason to instantiate a `String` if you've already got a literal `String`. But worse is the fact that the `matches()` method is out of place here.

What it does is greedily matching any character from the start to the end of a String. Then it backtracks until it finds `"Tutorials"`, after which it will again match any characters (except newlines).

It's better and more clear to use the [find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method. The find method simply finds the first `"Tutorials"` within the String, and you can remove the `"(.*)"` parts from the pattern.

As a one liner for convenience:

```
System.out.printf("Return value : %b%n", Pattern.compile("Tutorials").matcher("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com").find());
```